# How did Boltzmann know radiation pressure is 1/3 energy density?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I'm trying to tie up a loose end from Phillip Wood's answer [1] to [Boltzmann’s original derivation of the Stefan–Boltzmann law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319861/boltzmann-s-original-derivation-of-the-stefan-boltzmann-law) . In it he asserts:

> The radiation pressure,  is given by =/3. Radiation pressure was given a firm basis c1862 by Maxwell. The factor of 1/3 arises because of the three-dimensionality of the cavity, in which radiation is propagating in all possible directions. [It's easy for us now to derive this equation by considering the cavity as containing a photon gas.]

I'm curious how Maxwell, Boltzmann, and physicists of their era would have derived the relationship $p=u/3$. The Wikipedia article on the Stefan-Boltzmann law asserts this is due to the trace of the Electromagnetic stress-energy tensor vanishing [2]. The linked article on the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor [3] has enough information to confirm that the trace vanishes, but not the connection of the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor to pressure and energy density. It looks like section 35 of Landau & Lifshitz's Classical Theory of Fields has a derivation [4], but I'm having trouble following it. I'm hoping there's a simpler pre-quantum mechanics, non-photon gas derivation / explanation for why $p=u/3$. Can someone provide one / point to a more accessible explanation?

[1] https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/320561/236049

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Thermodynamic_derivation_of_the_energy_density

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor

[4] https://archive.org/details/LandauTheClassicalTheoryOfFields/page/n101/mode/2up

Comment: It's not hard to see that this is the case if you're willing to accept that the energy density of electromagnetic fields is $u = \frac{1}{2} (E^2 + B^2)$ and the momentum density is $\vec{\mathcal{p}}=\vec{E} \times \vec{B}$ (in appropriate units.)  But the derivation of those equations is dependent on the same techniques that lead to the stress-energy tensor, so if you're really looking for a start-from-Maxwell's equations derivation, you're stuck with understanding the stress-energy tensor.

Comment: There is a derivation of $p=u/3$ in Max Planck's book **The Theory of Heat Radiation**. It is available at Project Gutenberg and other places.